# Populate child collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

This is example from mongoose docs about populate:

```
const personSchema = Schema({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title: String,
});
```

So, `person` has list of `stories` and when we fetch `persons` we can include `stories` by using `populate('stories')`. So far so good.

But in order for that to work, when creating `Story`, we need to add `storyId` to `stories` list in `Person`. I am coming from `SQL` background, where that does not need to be done, it would find related `stories` automatically based on `authorId` on `Story`.

So the question is, can it be done in same way here, without need to update `stories` property on `Person`?

Comment: Clarity:   The `person` schema associates a name with 0 or more stories read (or whatever).    Not all names are authors -- but a `story` has an author and that must appear in `person`.  OK, but does that mean the author-as-person *must* now have their own story in stories?   If this was SQL, you would insert a new person first, then insert a new story with the author = new person.  What is different here except it is a push on the stories array vs. an insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, its called `virtual property`:

```
AuthorSchema.virtual('posts', {
  ref: 'BlogPost',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'author'
});
```

This way I can populate `posts` in query without saving `postIds` in `Author/Person` schema.